# Remove specific activation from agenda

Tags: clips

I just have started to learn CLIPS. I have a question that I didn't find any accurate answer for it on the web or in the CLIPS' ReferenceManual.

How (which command use) to remove specific activation from agenda? I use CLIPSIDE, and if you go to the top tab and choose "Browse" => "Agenda Manager",  you can remove specific activation from agenda. But i didn't find any command, which could do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding command for removing a specific activation from the agenda. That particular piece of functionality was included with the IDEs when first created over thirty years ago because of the belief that it might be useful when debugging. Since it hasn't turned out to be particularly useful, it was removed from the rewritten macOS IDE in CLIPS 6.3 and the rewritten Windows IDE in CLIPS 6.4.